# Find common rows in two dataframes and mark the common rows in the first one

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm working on a link prediction project on Spark using Scala. My goal is two find the common rows between two data frames (one of them contains the ground truth of all the links) and mark them in the first one. Thus the marked rows will represent existing lines.
For example, I have the below data frames:

```
+---+---+  +---+---+ 
|id1|id2|  |id1|id2|  
+---+---+  +---+---+  
| 2 | 3 |  | 4 | 1 | 
| 1 | 4 |  | 2 | 3 | 
+---+---+  +---+---+
```

And I want the result to be:

```
+---+---+-----+
|id1|id2|label|
+---+---+-----+
| 2 | 3 |  1  |
| 1 | 4 |  0  |
+---+---+-----+
```

Where 1 means that the link exists in the second data frame whereas 0 means the opposite. The links are directed.

Comment: Hi @Valentina, welcome to **StackOverflow**, you may take a look to [_"how to ask"_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve this and future questions. Specially you should provide some [_"research effort"_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and/or some code, to prove you already tried to solve the problem by yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do by left join between two dataframes in the following way:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.when
import spark.implicits._
val df1 = sc.parallelize(Seq((2,3),(1,4))).toDF("id1","id2")
val df2 = sc.parallelize(Seq((4,1),(2,3))).toDF("id1","id2")
val df3 = df1.join(df2, df1("id1")===df2("id1") && df1("id2") === df2("id2"), "left")
    .select(df1("id1"),
      df1("id2"),
      when(df2("id1").isNull, 0).otherwise(1).alias("label"))
df3.show()
+---+---+-----+
|id1|id2|label|
+---+---+-----+
|  2|  3|    1|
|  1|  4|    0|
+---+---+-----+
```

Hopefully it'll help you.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I needed. Thank you very much!